# Replace Key in Dictonary by another Dictonary and use loops Python3

Tags: python, loops, dictionary

thanks for help.

**1**. i have input dict:

```
populations = {
    'US-AL': 4887871,
    'US-AK': 737438,
    'US-AZ': 7171646}
```

and i have another input dict with
conformity USA states and Russia subject (this conformity doesn't matter, just like instance )
here it is "another" dict:

```
usa_rus = {
    'US-AL': 'RU-MOW',
    'US-AK': 'RU-KDA',
    'US-AZ': 'RU-SVE'}
```

**2**. My task is replace *key* in population dict. New *key* in population dict should be *value* from dict usa_rus. Another words, i want replace USA States in *key* to Russia subjects, *value* in dict population not changed.

**what i want in output:**

```
populations_new = {
    'RU-MOW': 4887871,
    'RU-KDA': 737438,
    'RU-SVE': 7171646}
```

**3**.Unfortunately, i haven't deep knowledge in python and creating dictionary, i'm studying.
I use only one solution but it is not clear:

```
list = []

for keys,values in populations.items():
    list.append({usa_rus[keys]:values})
```

***output:***

```
[{'RU-MOW': 4887871}, {'RU-KRS': 737438}, {'RU-SVE': 7171646}]
```

Please help me to make output which i want :)

Answer (score 2):

First, you shouldn't use Python reserved names as variable names, so rename your `list` variable.

Then, you want to use the `dict` to get the output to match your desired output. With minor changes to your code:

```
new_dict = dict()  # Or new_dict = {}
for key, value in usa_rus.items():
    new_dict[value] = populations[key]
```

Comment: thanks, you are right i will rename variable, thank you for solution!

Answer (score 2):

```
def convert(populations, usa_rus):
    result = {}
    for key, value in populations.items():
        if key in usa_rus.keys():
            result[usa_rus[key]] = value
        else:
            result[key] = value
    return result
    
populations = {
    'US-AL': 4887871,
    'US-AK': 737438,
    'US-AZ': 7171646}
usa_rus = {
    'US-AL': 'RU-MOW',
    'US-AK': 'RU-KDA',
    'US-AZ': 'RU-SVE'}

convert(populations, usa_rus)
print (populations)
```

Output:

```
{'RU-MOW': 4887871, 'RU-KDA': 737438, 'RU-SVE': 7171646}
```

Comment: cool, thank you for solution, great function could be useful in this kind tasks!

Answer (score 1):

```
for k, v in usa_rus.items():     
    if k in populations:
        populations[v] = populations.pop(k)
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier if you reverse the `usa_rus` dictionary:

```
>>> rus_usa = {r: u for u, r in usa_rus.items()}
>>> populations_new = {r: populations[rus_usa[r]] for r in rus_usa.keys()}
>>> populations_new
{'RU-MOW': 4887871, 'RU-KDA': 737438, 'RU-SVE': 7171646}
```

Comment: this is dangerous as a general practice, as a dict is a surjective mapping.